# Android Studio 3.3: Gradle Build Sync message is error FAILURE: Build failed with an exception

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

ERROR: Could not find method testImplementation() for arguments [junit:junit:4.12] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

I updated the android studio yesterday and created a new project but error during the gradle sync synchronization.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'D:\Android Project\dnm\app\build.gradle' line: 25
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

  > Could not find method testImplementation() for arguments [junit:junit:4.12] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

CONFİGURE FAILED in 25s
ERROR: Could not find method testImplementation() for arguments [junit:junit:4.12] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
Open File

```
buildscript
{
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()  
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0' } 
}
allprojects { 
    repositories { 
        google() 
        jcenter() 
    }
}
```

and my gradle properties

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.1-all.zip
```

and my gradle build

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.denemeuygulamasi.dnm"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today I had same issue , after update to 3.3

I uninstall and delete gradle directory android directory etc nothing worked but then I wrote

testİmplementation instead of testImplementation and androidTestİmplementation

it worked basically , I don't know why , but you can try and write if you find better solution please because I have to do this to every project I create

Comment: Could you tell step by step ? I don't understand sorry androboy.

Comment: By the way, I deleted android studio, .gradle and files etc... I installed again but I got same problem!!!

Answer (score 1):

Did you add it's dependency?

I think you need to add in build gradle dependencies

testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

Or delete .gradle and .idea then invalidate cache and restart 
[image]

Comment: Yes @Khaled Qasem, I did. I added above my dependencies.

Comment: Make sure that you have apply plugin: 'com.android.application' in build.gradle then sync the project and let me know if it works fine

Comment: I have typed up my gradle file completely (above update). I tried "File - Sync Project with Gradle Files" but not work, I get the same error.

Comment: I added androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1' and 
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1' but not work, same error. How to make it compatible ? Step-by-step

Comment: okay replace androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2' 
with androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.1.1'

then replace androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2' with androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'

Comment: In case you have a lot of issues and don't use testing delete them 
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

Comment: I replaced, but not again. So I tried to delete  testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12' androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2' androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2' , tataaaaa :) Succeed. Thanks but my apps, I am testing on my device, I wonder if I have another problem for delete files.

Comment: Is androidTestImplementation optional ? doesn't matter in my app, right?

Comment: In fact delete them not a good solution, this solution just a workaround, by deleting them you will not be able to write a test cases for your code so we need to handle this issue.

Comment: Oww, Then I need to find a healthier solution, right ? but How ?

Comment: Did you try invalidate cache and restart when after updating, Add them and try it.
File -> Invalidate cache and restart.
Make sure that your dependancies like this : 
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}

Comment: Do you have a different solution because it only deleted succeed

Comment: I have edited the answer check it please @SeptikArgonot

Comment: Thanks, I tried again but not worked :( @Khaled Qasem, my project was stop, don't believe it, I don't find any solution

Comment: By the way, I deleted android studio, .gradle and files etc... I installed again but I got same problem!!!